# I need help with "be involved" in and "involve in"

Tags: grammaticality, phrasal-verbs

I don't understand the difference between "be involved in" and "involve in" in the following sentences:

> (1). My former teacher **was involved** in biology and related research for ten years.
>   (2). My former teacher **involved** in biology and related research for ten years.

Comment: "Was involved in and involved himself in"  conveys the same sense, but I think it's not right to say that my former teacher involved in biology....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second sentence is not grammatical.

When *involved* is used as a transitive verb, the subject is almost always an activity or a field of knowledge, never an animate noun.

> Climbing mountains involves a lot of risk.
>
> Proper exercise involves physical as well as mental discipline.
>
> Does this job involve travel?

A person may only be **involved in** something. It's a non-specific way of signifying someone's participation in an activity.

> He's been involved in the chess club for several years.
>
> She's heavily involved in the church choir; she's at rehearsal 3 nights a week.

However, there are some cases where a person can be the subject or object of *involve*.

> I want to involve Tom in my plan to rob the bank.
>
> Now Tom is involved in the bank robbery.

**Involved with** signifies a personal relationship, usually - but not always - romantic.

> How long have they been involved?
>
> She's been involved with him for three years.
>
> I don't like the group of friends he's involved with.

Comment: "When involved is used as a transitive verb" 1) Can you list the situations where 'involved' is used as an intransitive verb? 2) "A person may only be involved in something" really? What about "involve oneself"?

Comment: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/involve  Parents should involve themselves in their child's education

Comment: I'm sorry, you're correct that it's a transitive verb. I should have said active or passive voice. "to be involved in" is passive, and "to involve" is active. I think most English speakers tend to use it in the passive form, which makes it easy to forget that it's actually a transitive verb.